# How to add marker on specific location longitude and latitude as input field?

Tags: html, jquery, css, openlayers

I am trying to add marker on location based on html input field longitude and latitude. After providing input and click on search button which is calling function goToLocation the result should show marker on that location, but after executing this function only location is zoom but no marker is visible. I am using open layer 4.5 version and Here is my code with the function:

```
function goToLocation() {

    vectorSource.clear();
    var f = "{ \"type\": \"Feature\",\"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [" + $('#input-longitude').val() + "," + $('#input-latitude').val() + "]}}";
    //  var f2 = "{ \"type\": \"Feature\",\"geometry\": { \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [" + $('#input-longitude').val() + "," + $('#input-latitude').val() + "]}}";

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
            anchor: [0.5, 46],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 0.75,
            src: 'img/marker.png'

        }))
    });



    var myFeature = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeature(f);
    myFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    vectorSource.addFeature(myFeature);

    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());

    map.getView().setZoom(12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OL is sensible to the input type. Sometimes you can use a string for the coordinates, and sometimes not, it must be a float.

The solution is to parse the coordinates

```
parseFloat($('#input-longitude').val())
```

Also make sure that the user used a `.` to separate the decimals, not a `,`

PS: that being said, you don't need to construct a GeoJson and to re-parse it again.

```
myVectorSource.addFeature( 
   new Feature( {geometry: new Point([parseFloat($('#input-longitude').text()),  
                                      parseFloat($('#input-longitude').text())]),
                name: String($('#input-myname').text()),
                }));
```

Comment: first thank you for your reply but I can't define myVectorSource as new feature because it is giving me undefined of new Feature that because I am using in another script.js. The problem is I see myfeature with all elements that I need while I am debugging and also I am not receiving any error but I am not able to see on the map? any suggestions or help? thank you in advance

Comment: I tried but it's not working as you can read from my question above the location is working and zooming without parsing the values. But not showing marker on the specific longitude and latitude

Comment: If you are using full build the syntax is `new ol.Feature` and `new ol.geom.Point`